# Checking if website responds in python using a browser user agent

Tags: python, web, request, dns, resolve

I am trying to come up with a script to check if a domain name resolves to its IP address via dns; using a python script I wrote.

I want to be able to do this in a few sequential loops, however after trying to run a loop once, the second time i run the script, the names that previously returned a successful dns resolution response, now do not.

Below is my script:

```
#! C:\Python27
import socket,time

localtime = time.asctime( time.localtime(time.time()) )


def hostres(hostname):
    print "Attempting to resolve " + hostname 
    try:
        socket.gethostbyname(hostname)
        print "Resolved Successfully!"
    except socket.error:
        print "Could Not Resolve"

print "*************************************************"
print "Website loop starting.."
print "Local current time :", localtime
print "*************************************************"
print ""

text_file = open("sites.txt", "r")
lines = text_file.readlines()
for line in lines:
    hostres(line)
text_file.close()
```

The contents of the text file are:

```
www.google.com
en.wikipedia.org
www.youtube.com
us.gamespot.com
```

I am thinking it is to do with these domains servers recognizing the script as a "bot" rather than a legitimate end-user, would it be correct to assume this?

If so, how can I still check if the dns name resolves by looking up the name of the website (or IP, does not matter) and be able to run this without getting a false reading of "request failed" despite the fact that the service is fully accessible from a browser?

Comment: I don't see any problems with this code, and it works fine for me. Maybe there's a problem with your network setup or something like this?

Comment: So it runs fine without negative responses on subsequent runs?

Comment: I keep getting "could not resolve" for all of them, tried testing on linux and winXP (using IDLE).

Comment: Could you try running the script from command line instead inside of IDLE?

Comment: OK, tried running from CMD in windows, and i get the same result.

Comment: This is certainly a problem with the dns configuration on the box you are running it.  I pasted the same code into IDLE, python2.7 on windows 7 and all 4 addresses resolved.  Consider asking for help on http://superuser.com/

Comment: I get "socket.gaierror: [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname" error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several problems in this question.

1. You are not checking if "a website responds" you are testing DNS resolution. All your DNS requests go to a single name server, your LDNS resolver. If all of them resolve, it still says nothing about the status of the **website**. Also, since you aren't actually talking to these website, they have no way of knowing you're a bot. They can only detect this (based on the HTTP user-agent header) if you make a HTTP request.
2. Regarding your code problem, you need to trim the newline character before you can do a socket.gethostbyname() on it. Replace `socket.gethostbyname(hostname)` with `socket.gethostbyname(hostname.rstrip())` and you'll be fine.